# Code doesn't run in order? Updates to DOM happen all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsxgraph

I'm having a bit of trouble with running my code in order.  Basically I have a function that hides an element, console log a message then run another function that makes a slow and massive change to the DOM.

Ideally the hide occurs first to signal the user response has been made, then they can deal with the lag for a few seconds as everything refreshes.  But right now, the console gets logged first, then all the changes happen at once after a few seconds.  So the hide occurs together with the updates.

If it makes any difference, the update function creates and destroys several div elements, then starts creating JSXGraphs and updating functions, points, etc on those graphs.

```
check_answer(answer_input) {
  if (this.ans == answer_input) {
    $("#answer-card-section").hide();
    console.log("CORRECT!");

    current_question.update();
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing long running functions in JS the calls to render the UI can be blocked. In some cases it can also prevent the previous operation from visibly updating the DOM, which is what you're seeing here.

The simple fix is to put the `update()` call within a timeout with a short delay. This will allow the `hide()` to update the DOM first. Try this:

```
function check_answer(answer_input) {
  if (this.ans == answer_input) {
    $("#answer-card-section").hide();

    setTimeout(function() {
      current_question.update();
    }, 25);
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, but I have to wonder if this is good practice.  Is there a function to force the update of the DOM?

Comment: Nope. This isn't great practice, and is frankly a bit of a code smell. I'd suggest refactoring the `update()` function so it's not such an intensive process instead. How you do that we can't really help you with, though

Comment: It'll have to do for now, I only have a single page with this much info so it's not too bad.  But while playing around with it, I found a few ways to optimize my larger function, so hopefully I can avoid it entirely.  It just... kinda bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to execute a callback function after all the `hide`-operations are finished. One way to achieve this in jQuery is to use `$.when().done`:

```
function check_answer(answer_input) {
  if (this.ans == answer_input) {
    $.when( $("#answer-card-section").hide() ).done(function() {
      current_question.update();
    });
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But beware, in general the return of this function will happen before `current_question.update()` has been finished.

Comment: This won't change anything as `hide()` is not an asynchronous call.